# How To Use Traverse To Run A List of Effects

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have a function like this:

```scala
 def getFile(url: String): EitherT[Future, Error, ByteString]
```

This is using cats EitherT.

I call this function using another function like this:

```scala
def getAllFiles(urls: List[String]): EitherT[Future, Error, List[ByteString]] = {
    urls.map(f => getFile(f).value)
  }
```

This doesn't work as I get type mismatch:

```scala
found   : List[scala.concurrent.Future[Either[Error,akka.util.ByteString]]]
[error]  required: cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,Error,List[akka.util.ByteString]]
```

No matter what I try I can't this to compile. Basically what I want to do is to run getFile for each URL and download the file in Bytestring.

Comment: If you are going to use **cats** I would recommend you to use `IO` instead of `Future`.

Comment: This is inside Scala Play so I am forced to use Future. Future is everywhere in Play

Comment: Not really, you can use `IO` for your code and then when passing the value to **play** you call `unsafeToFuture()` and if you have a function that already returns a `Future`, you can call `IO.fromFuture(IO(foo))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.implicits._

type Error = String
type ByteString = Array[Byte]

def getFile(url: String): EitherT[IO, Error, ByteString] = ???

def getAllFiles(urls: List[String]): EitherT[IO, Error, List[ByteString]] =
  urls.traverse(getFile)
```

But this don't:

```
def getFile(url: String): EitherT[Future, Error, ByteString] = ???

def getAllFiles(urls: List[String]): EitherT[Future, Error, List[ByteString]] =
  urls.traverse(getFile)
```

The reason is that `traverse` expects an **Applicative** from the nested effect, which **cats** provides for `IO` but not for `Future`.

---

So, the reason is that due the eager and cached nature of **Future**, we can not really reason about its behavior. So **cats** doesn't provide instances for it.
You may provide your own **Applicative** for `Future`... but, IMHO, it would be easier to just adapt the code using `IO.fromFuture` and `io.unsafeToFuture()`

Comment: So it is impossible with Future?

Comment: @Mojo see the edited answer, I am sorry, I pressed enter by accident.

Comment: Just so I understand, EitherT is not an applicative but Future is?

Comment: @Mojo `EitherT[F, E, A]` can be an **Applicative** if `F[_]` is one. But, we do not have an instance of **Applicative** for `Future`, but we do for `IO`.

Comment: I think I also need to provide these right:   private implicit val cs = IO.contextShift(executionContext)
  private implicit val timer = IO.timer(executionContext)

Comment: it is complaining about these

Comment: @Mojo for the `traverse` I am sure not, but maybe you do need them, for your implementations. If you can use **IOApp** for your main. it will give you those, so you only need to ask for them as implicit parameters, if not, try to only instantiate them just one time and pass them implicitly over all your app.